# How can I assert in VBScript scripts?

Tags: vbscript, assert

What is a good way to use [asserts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assertion_%28computing%29) in [VBScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VBScript) scripts?

Is there built-in functionality for it or will it have to be emulated? What is best practice?

One application is to test for objects being `Nothing` during development.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An operational answer (for others that may need it) is to define this function, from [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Assertions#VBScript):

```
    sub Assert( boolExpr, strOnFail )
        if not boolExpr then
            Err.Raise vbObjectError + 99999, , strOnFail
        end if
    end sub
```

Invocation:

```
    Set obj2 = Nothing
    Assert Not obj2 Is Nothing, "obj2 is Nothing!"
```

Output:

```
    someScript.vbs(17, 3) (null): obj2 is Nothing!
```

Comment: Rosetta Code is a very interesting site.  Thanks and a +1 for the link.

Comment: @Knox: I didn't discover Rosetta Code until today. And I agree: it seems to be a very interesting site.

Answer (score 3):

Sadly, I don't believe VBScript has anything built-in. You'll need to define your own `Assert` method and probably use a pre-processor build script or something to remove them when building a release copy of your script. (Actually removing -- at least commenting out -- the `Assert` call is best, rather than just making the body of the `Assert` not do anything in the released code.)